# How is type of limit solved?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have trouble solving this limit $$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left ( \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )^{\frac{-2x+1}{x}}$$ Can someone show the steps and the reasoning behind the solution?

Comment: Has one of these answers helped you understand and answer your problem? If so, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by using this little trick:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\bigg)^{\frac{1-2x}{x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \exp \ln\bigg(\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\bigg)^{\frac{1-2x}{x}}$$
$$=\exp \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-2x}{x}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\bigg)$$
And, since the limit of a product is equal to the product of a limit, we have
$$=\exp \bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-2x}{x}\bigg)\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\bigg)\bigg)$$
$$=\exp (-2)\ln\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\bigg)$$
$$=\exp (-2)\ln\bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)$$
$$=\bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^{-2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{9}$$

This is basically the same as the solution left by @tong_nor, but it is a little bit more rigorous and does not require a proof of the claim he makes.

Comment: Also, this is the method you'd want to use if you did have a case of "$1^\infty$". You'd eventually be able to get to a place where you can use L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @BlakeSplitter Right, that's why I prefer it - I don't have to worry about that troublesome case.

Comment: @Nilknarf Thanks for the answer. Can you provide more parentheses in the solution where you use exp, lim, and log to be more readable?

Comment: Note: It'd probably be easier to read if you had one more set of parentheses: $$=\exp\left(\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-2x}{x}\bigg)\bigg(\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\bigg)\bigg)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \to 3/2$$

$$\frac{-2x+1}{x} \to -2$$

Answer (score 2):

The thing inside tends to $\frac{3}{2}$, the exponent tends to $-2$.

In this case $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$ is just $(\lim f(x))^{\lim g(x)}$.

---

Remember that you cannot use this rule when $f(x)\to 1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ ! ($1^\infty$ is not $1$)

Comment: Thanks for the second point. Can you point to a reference for it's proof?

Comment: take the logarithm of the power, it will be a product ($\ln f^g=g\ln f$), then deal with the product and finally take the exponent - this is how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\ln{x}$ are continuous functions, we obtain:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left ( \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )^{\frac{-2x+1}{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}e^{\frac{-2x+1}{x}\ln\left ( \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{-2x+1}{x}\ln\frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{-2x+1}{x}\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\ln \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} }=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{-2x+1}{x}\ln\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-3x}{1-2x} }=e^{-2\cdot\ln\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{4}{9}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$A=\left ( \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )^{\frac{-2x+1}{x}}$$ take logarithms $$\log(A)=\frac{-2x+1}{x}\log\left ( \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )=\frac{-2x+1}{x}\log\left ( \frac{3-\frac1x}{2-\frac 1x} \right )$$ Now, using Taylor expansion $$\log(a-\epsilon)=\log (a)-\frac{\epsilon }{a}+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ and applying twice leads to  $$\log\left ( \frac{3-\frac1x}{2-\frac 1x} \right )=\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{6 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ $$\log(A)=-2 \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{\log
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{3}}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ Now, using $$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{4}{9}+\frac{4 \left(\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{3}\right)}{9
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Try using a calculator for $x=10$, the exact value is $\frac{19}{29} \left(\frac{19}{29}\right)^{9/10}\approx 0.447791$ while the above expansion would give $\frac{2}{135} \left(29+\log \left(\frac{27}{8}\right)\right)\approx 0.447650$ that is to say a relative error of $0.03$%.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an indetermination. The base tends to $\dfrac{3}{2}$ the exponent to $-2$ the limit is $\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^{-2}=\dfrac{4}{9}$